# Android background BLE beacon scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I want to create an android application with background scanning of BLE beacon (like Eddystone or ibeacon). All I need is the detection of a beacon with a specific ID on my phone. I do not need distance between devices.

1. Is there any beacon with the ability to send signals through cca 3 walls in a building (or 1 flood up/down) in an area with a radius around 30m?
2. Can my app scan in the background every few seconds all day? (or just when Bluetooth is on, obviously...)

I tried some solutions, but android changed some politics about background running apps, or bluetooth receiver (to detect, when bluetooth is on). My solution sometimes works even 7 hours, but when I restart phone, the app is not restarted. I want a full background run, not foreground service with notification.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

1. All bluetooth beacon formats use the same radio transport mechanism.  Radio power is limited by international regulatory bodies making transmitters weak.
   The laws of physics decide how well they will travel between floors of a building, which will vary based on construction materials, but results will generally be poor.  Again, this will be the same for all beacon formats.
2. Android 8+ limits detections of BLE in the background without a foreground service.  You can do at most one scan every 10-25 minutes (this is randomized) when the phone is not in deep sleep mode.  the only alternative is a foreground service with an ever present notification.

I realize these are not the answers you want to hear, but it is important to recognize and accept real-world limitations that exist and come up with creative solutions that work within these limitations.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.

Comment: So let say, that one scan every 10 - 25 minutes is enought for me. And a user will be using his phone at least 45 minutes before he comes into the range of the beacon. Can I be sure, that app will work? Or phone restart, or custom battery saver on Samsung, Huaweii etc. will kill it?

Comment: In general, yes, this works.  But sadly, nothing in the life of Android background apps is simple!  All newer Android devices have some kind of battery saver feature that can disable apps in the background.   Chinese OEMs like Huawei typically have user-editable app whitelists, and any app not on the whitelist will eventually be denied background running time.  On open source Android (Pixel, Android One) and Samsung App Standby buckets are used.  If a user does not interact with an app for multiple days, background operations will be disabled.  It is possible for the user to disable this.